# Does "spring data cassandra" have client side loadbalancing?

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I'm operating project using spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra.

When I setup that project, I set cassandra properties by ip and port.
(referred by https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-cassandra-tutorial)

When set it up like this, If I had 3 cassandra nodes and 1 cassandra node died, I think project should fail to connect with cassandra at a 33% probability.

But my project was fine even though 1 cassandra node was dead. (just have some error on one's deathbed)

Do It happen to have A function in spring-data-cassandra like client-side-loadbalancing?

If they have that function, Where can I see that code??

I tried to find that code but failed.

Please give me a little clue.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Data Cassandra relies on the functionality of the [DataStax Java driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/) that is responsible for making everything works.  This includes:

- establishing the initial connection to the cluster. This is where the contact points play their role.  After driver is connected to any of points, it reads information about the whole cluster and establishes connections to all nodes (by default)
- establishing the [control connection](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/control_connection/) that is used to receive notifications about changes in the cluster - nodes going up & down, changes in schema, etc.  If node goes down or up, this information is used to modify the list of the active nodes
- providing the load balancing of requests based on the replication, and nodes availability - if the node is down, it's excluded from list of candidates, so we don't send queries to node that is known to be down